# How to write an alias to accept variables

Tags: bash, script

I want to set an alias so that I can swiftly log in to one of my workstations. For example, I must enter

```
ssh root@c1232-node1.example.com
```

to log in to one of my machines. Sometimes, the hostname could be `c1232-node2` or `c1232-node3`, but the domain name would always be *example.com*.

I want to add the alias permanently in my `.zshrc` file so that I need not set it every time I open the terminal.

I did my research, and I was successful using a function such as below:

```
ssh_node() { ssh root@"$1".example.com; }
```

But when I add this function into my `.zshrc` and run the `source` command on it, it complains and doesn't accept the function.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

So dumb of me. I achieved my goal by adding this line to the `.zshrc`:

```
cluster() { ssh root@"$1".example.com; }
```

And then did a

```
source .zshrc
```

Running `cluster c1232-node3` executes `ssh root@c1232-node3.example.com`. Mission complete!